Air Plant Care While on Vacation
We're going on a 4 week vacation. How do I prepare my air plants? Perhaps a closed terrarium  to maintain humidity just for the time we're gone?

Sounds good.Thank you for the advice.

A closed terrarium lacks air circulation.  Tillandsia like humid air with diffuse light and plenty of air circulation.  If you have anyone coming over to check on the house just putting the plant in water for a few minutes every few days will do.  Or a terrarium that is in indirect bright light should be good enough.
